# Does this sentence make sense? (I reformed the cloth into a dress.)

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request

When I want to express that I reformed the cloth and made a dress, can I say like 'I reformed the cloth into a dress?

If I am wrong, What is the best answer for it?

Comment: I don't think the verb "reform" is a proper one here, and nor is "reuse" (use again). Why not simply "I used the cloth to make a dress" or "I made a dress from the cloth"?

Comment: Did you cut and sew the cloth to make the dress?  Did you melt (or unravel) the cloth, and resolidify (or reknit/reweave) the cloth to make the dress?  Or did you pin it together in the shape of a toga?

Comment: I don't know why people don't like "reform". It is a perfectly apt word here. But I guess the sentiment against it suggests that it has the wrong *connotation*, and choosing an alternative may be a good idea.

Comment: @CodyGray: I agree. It sounds like somebody is a magic user, which of course is not true.

Comment: To clarify, are you using "new" cloth (that is cloth that hasn't be used before to make something else) to make the dress?

Comment: Even if I found this the best word to use (which I would mainly determine based on "does 'formed' make sense?" and "was it formed [into something else, or another dress that was then undone] before?") I would probably spell it as "re-formed" and pronounce it differently. Likewise with any other verb where a "re" prefix gives it a different (even if related) meaning - recoil (i recoiled the wire), recollect, review, etc.

Comment: @박용현 Are you pronouncing the word "re-formed" (two stressed syllables) or "reformed" (with an unstressed *re*)?

Answer (score 11):

Using *reformed* sounds rather odd. If you *reform* something, you improve it, you don't change it into something else. So, if you *reform* an electoral system, it is still an electoral system, but (hopefully) a better one. Using either *turned* or *made* would be more appropriate:

> - I turned the cloth into a dress.
> - I made the cloth into a dress.

Or even:

> - I transformed the cloth into a dress.

But that sound a little pretentious.

Comment: He didn't "change it into something else." It's still cloth, it's just now in the shape of a dress. Any definition of "reform" is consistent with this meaning: *e.g.*, to change the shape or form; improve by alteration. Using "reform[ed]" is perfectly fine here; this answer is wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray Having been involved in the garment industry all my life, I can honestly say that I have never heard of some fabric being *reformed* into a garment. Generally speaking, fabric is *made* into garments. (Although hats can be *formed* on a *forming machine*.)

Comment: @Cody - Completely disagree with your assessment. The way I've seen the word typically used aligns with what I find in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reform), which says that _reform_ applies to institutions and individuals, not a bolt of cloth. Similarly, [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/reform_2), gives specific mention to systems and behaviors. While I wouldn't say that such definitions rigidly preclude extended or figurative usages, I heartily agree that it sounds a bit odd, and these suggestions constitute improvements.

Comment: *Re-formed* with two stressed syllables might be acceptable (though odd), but the normal word *reformed* has the wrong meaning.

Answer (score 8):

One could simply say *reuse* in this context.

> - I **reused** the cloth to make a dress

A slightly fancier way of saying the same would be:

> - I **repurposed** the cloth to make a dress.

In both cases, the prefix *re-* gives the sense the the cloth had a previous purpose or form, rather than being a fresh piece of cloth.

Comment: I think "reusing" sounds more like simply used it again in its original shape as well in the same way, perhaps especially if it should not get used twice: "It was the only comdom, so I've reused it" 

And *repurposed* means that it got not changed but used it in another kind of way as it was originally meant: "The dress was worn out, so I repurposed it as a diaper"

Answer (score 7):

Using "reform" this way might be allowed by the rules of the language, but it is definitely not idiomatic. A native speaker would not say that. A native speaker would more likely say "I made a dress from the cloth".

Answer (score 3):

It's not that "reform" is unacceptable -- it's an awkward use of the word. I like the suggestion of "transform". In the context of dress making it implies that the dress was not simply crafted from cloth, but that the designer was an artist who elevated the cloth to a higher purpose.

Comment: I do not think that I would used it to describe the work of an artist, he would simply *craft* something from it, as for the creation of the dress. Both handicraft is a craftsmanship as well as tailoring.

*to transform* means in general to change the form of something: blowing up a ballon and also the transformation of carbon like coal into diamonds.

Answer (score 2):

Reform is incorrect in this case, because it describes taking a *working form* and turning it into *another working form*. *Re* - a latin prefix meaning "again" - implies that the subject was previously formed, but raw materials such as cloth are by definition not yet formed.

It would be correct to say that you *formed* the cloth into a dress. It wouldn't be the best word for this case; *formed* is old-fashioned and not very specific. You might have *sewed*, *cut*, or even *fabricated* the cloth into a dress, and those would be better options.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one example where "I reformed the cloth into a dress" would be accurate.  "Form" can describe forcing something into a shape.  Fabric can be "molded" or forced into a custom shape (other than flat), by mechanical processes.  If you start with cloth that was formed into a shape for some purpose and decide to reuse it to make a dress employing a similar shaping process, you could say you reformed the cloth into a dress.  A forming process certainly isn't a typical way to make a dress, but that would be the literal meaning of the sentence in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To say that you made a dress out of cloth it would be a good choice to use the verb [to craft](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/craft%5D):

```
craft
verb [ T often passive ]
UK  /krɑːft/ US  /kræft/
 
to make objects, especially in a skilled way:
These bracelets were crafted by Native Americans.
a beautifully crafted silver brooch
```

It works also for most work done by hand, at least everything which counts as [craftmansship](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/craftsmanship), e.g. *tailoring*, *sewing*, *forging*, *creation of art*, etc. .